# Should I edit a closed issue with the issue summary template?

Tags: community-official-site

Once you go to create a [new issue](https://www.drupal.org/node/add/project-issue/drupal) in drupal.org you can see a message that says:

> Learn [how to report an issue](https://www.drupal.org/node/73179). Use the [issue summary template](https://www.drupal.org/node/1155816) to
>   summarize the issue in the Description field below. Others can also
>   change the summary. Editing the summary does not subscribe you to the
>   issue or notify subscribers, so add a comment describing your changes
>   after any significant edit.

But there are some closed issues like [Incorrect call to urldecode()](https://www.drupal.org/node/1569580) in the [www.drupal.org](http://www.drupal.org) site that don't follow the template format.

Should I edit a closed issue with the issue summary template?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. It's completely appropriate to edit an issue to clarify the findings, solutions, workarounds etc. and make it easier for people who may look to that issue for reference.

Comment: thanks, this can include edit the commit message to change the title according to the edit?

Comment: All too often the paperwork is not covered

Comment: @LittleCoding What's the paperwork? Sorry but I'm not an english speaker.

Comment: The supporting documentation would be the "paperwork".